# Is this a simpler proof that all transformations mapping D(1:0) onto D(1;0) are of the form $\;\;e^{i\lambda}\frac{z-\alpha}{\bar{\alpha}z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, mobius-transformation

The question is from an exercise (2.13) in Introduction to Complex Analysis by H.A. Priestley. Before writing this I did check all the questions that might have the answer, but where proofs were given I wasn't able to follow them. (Sorry—self studying beginner here).

So I went back to the inverse points form of a circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

$$|z-\alpha|=\lambda|z-\beta|$$

It is straightforward to show (and Priestley does this) that the condition for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be inverse points for

$$|z-a|=r$$ is that $$(\alpha-a)(\overline{\beta-\alpha})=r^2$$

In the case of the unit circle this gives: $\,\alpha\bar{\beta}=1\;$ie one point is the inverse of the conjugate of the other. Which gives the inverse point equation as

$$\left|\frac{z-\alpha}{z-\frac{1}{\bar\alpha}}\right|=\lambda$$ but the circle goes through (1,0) so $$\left|\frac{1-\alpha}{1-\frac{1}{\bar\alpha}}\right|=\lambda=\left|\frac{\bar{\alpha}(1-\alpha)}{\bar{\alpha}-1}\right|$$

and as $|1-\alpha|=|\bar{\alpha}-1|,\;\;$$\lambda=\bar{\alpha}\;$ which gives for the unit disc the equation $$\left|\frac{z-\alpha}{\bar{\alpha}z-1}\right|\lt1$$

As the equation for the unit disc is also $|z|\lt1\;\;$ the transformation $f(z)= $$\left(\frac{z-\alpha}{\bar{\alpha}z-1}\right)$ maps D(0;1) onto D(0;1).

Finally, my question: does having derived this Mobius transformation from the general circle in $\mathbb{C}\;$ constitute a (non-rigorous) proof that all transformations that map D(0;1) onto D(0;1) are of this form or a rotation of it, ie $\;\;e^{i\lambda}\frac{z-\alpha}{\bar{\alpha}z-1}$?

Comment: Note that you're not required to show that any $w = e^{i \lambda} (z - \alpha)/(\overline \alpha z - 1)$ is $\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ (which would be false). Instead, the question is: if you're given some mapping $\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$, is it true that it can be written in the form $w$? Now, do you want to prove this a) for all conformal mappings or b) for Mobius transformations? a) is true, but is slightly more difficult to prove. b) easily follows from the fact that conjugation wrt generalized circles is preserved.

Comment: @Maxim. I had to leave out 'Mobius' because of character limitations. I also had to leave out bits of the original question. It reads: Prove...that every Mobius transformation mapping D(0;1) onto D(0;1) is of the form $e^{i\lambda} (z-\alpha)/(\bar \alpha z-1)$ for some real constant $\lambda$ and some $\alpha \in  D(0;1).$ This doesn't seem to be the same as I led you to believe. Does the 'proof'' work for this question?

Comment: The conclusion of your proof is that the transformation $w$ is $\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$. I'm saying that you're required to prove the converse statement: any $(a z + b)/(c z +d)$ which is $\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ can be written in the form $w$.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you. I was hoping that deriving the transformation from a general circle would make the transformation general enough to show that any $(az+b)/(cz+d)$ would be of the same form. Back to the drawing board? Should I delete the question? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you need to delete the question. Regarding a possible proof, one way is to use the conjugation property that I mentioned. Then the proofs for both the direct and the converse statements are essentially one-liners.

Comment: I'm afraid there was a term in that part of your answer I didn't understand—"wrt".. May I bother you for an explanation? Many thanks!

Comment: Google is your friend :). It's w.r.t., "with respect to".

Comment: Don't use Google but I get your point! Many thanks.